How to correctly run AppleScript on Mail.app via NSAppleScript and parse results as a list of strings
I've the following code that I would like to use to get a list of the email accounts available within the Mail.app.
import Foundation

struct EmailAccounts {
    func getAccountNames() -> [String] {
        let appleScriptSource = """
        tell application "Mail"
            set accountDict to {}
            repeat with acc in accounts
                set accName to name of acc
                set accEmails to email addresses of acc
                set accountDict's end to {accName:accEmails}
            end repeat
            return accountDict
        end tell
        """

        var error: NSDictionary?
        var accountNames: [String] = []

        if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: appleScriptSource) {
            let scriptResult = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
            if let listDescriptor = scriptResult.coerce(toDescriptorType: typeAEList) {
                for index in 1...listDescriptor.numberOfItems {
                    if let listItemString = listDescriptor.atIndex(index)?.stringValue {
                        accountNames.append(listItemString)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return accountNames

    }
}

Debugging, would suggest that scriptResult.coerce(toDescriptorType: typeAEList) evaluates to nil as breakpoints set below, within the loop are not hit.
The AppleScript evaluates without a problem returning a list of account names and associated email addresses
tell application "Mail"
    set accountInfoList to {}
    repeat with acc in accounts
        set accName to name of acc
        set accEmails to email addresses of acc
        set end of accountInfoList to {accName, accEmails}
    end repeat
    return accountInfoList
end tell


Question: How can I utilise the scriptResult object to arrive at array of strings representing output obtained via AppleScript?

At the moment I'm ignoring the fact that outputs should be treated as a nested array with multiple email addresses attached to a single account, but I can deal with this minor issue later.

scriptResult is already a list; you cannot coerce it. Just go right ahead and start dealing with it as a list:
for index in 1...scriptResult.numberOfItems {
    print(scriptResult.atIndex(index)?.isRecordDescriptor)
}

This will prove to you that you have a list of as many AppleScript records as there are accounts. Now go ahead and deal with your "minor issue", i.e. how to get the info out of each AppleScript record.

Thanks, useful and clear answer. Follow up question, why scriptResult.atIndex(index)? is an optional? There may be no scriptResult at a specific index?

.atIndex returns an Optional because (1) the recipient  NSAppleEventDescriptor might not be a list, or (2) the parameter might be out of bounds. — If you have further questions (and I expect you will, since I expect you to discover that the entire approach you've chosen is untenable), please use the Ask Question button at the top right of this page.
